# EOF VBA blocks me from accessing last line of my file

Tags: vba, while-loop, readfile, eof, do-loops

I am trying to loop through a text file. I do specific check on each line of this file to know if it will be pasted or not. I am using the following code. But using EOF blocks me from accessing the last line, which can be useful sometimes.

```
Dim buffer As String
Open file For Input As #1

Line Input #1, buffer
i = 1
j = 1

Do Until EOF(1) And i > coll(coll.Count)

    If i = coll(j) Then 
         ListSplit = Split(buffer, ",") 'Split the line with "," delimiter
         '...
         j=j+1
    End If

    Line Input #1, buffer
    i = i + 1

Loop 

Close #1
```

Comment: Put the test at the end of the loop rather than at the start.

Comment: I put at the end like:
Do 
....
Loop Until EOF(1)

But it doesn't look to be working, I have the same issue.

Comment: Should  it reaaly be if j>coll(coll.count)

Comment: This part can be removed. Even with test on EOF only, it doesn't work. Last line is not considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structure your logic like this:

```
   Open file For Input As #1
   
   Do
      Line Input #1, buffer
      Debug.Print buffer  'do your work
   Loop Until EOF(1)
   
   Close #1
```

The issue with the code you posted is that the last line is read, which sets EOF, and then you loop.  The condition is evaluated and the loop is exited.